# PetaPoco doesn't throw an exception

Tags: c#, petapoco

I am using PetaPoco and have the following code to get a list of names from the database.

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetManufacturers()
{
    try
    {
        statement = "EXEC P_GET_ALL_MANUFACTURER_NAMES";
        var data = db.Query<string>(statement);
        return data;
    }
    catch (SqlException sqlex)
    {
        LogManager.WriteException(sqlex);
        throw;
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException ioex)
    {
        LogManager.WriteException(ioex);
        throw;
    }
}
```

When the stored procedure doesn't exist in the database, I noticed that the exception isn't being caught in the catch block and is being written to the `data` variable which is being written to the API layer above where it is getting rendered as a JSON object.

```
{
    "Message" : "An error has occurred.",
    "ExceptionMessage" : "The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'.",
    "ExceptionType" : "System.InvalidOperationException",
    "StackTrace" : null,
    "InnerException" : {
        "Message" : "An error has occurred.",
        "ExceptionMessage" : "Could not find stored procedure 'P_GET_ALL_MANUFACTURER_NAMES'.",
        "ExceptionType" : "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException",
        "StackTrace" : "..."
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? How can I get PetaPoco to throw the exception?

Comment: Could it be that since you are telling PetaPoco to expect a string and it gets one that it does not see anything wrong?  Have you tried creating a class to hold the returned data?

Comment: Shit! okay that was stupid.

Comment: Have you solved it?

Comment: No, I avoided the problem for the time being by making sure the stored proc is available. I tried having a class with a string property, but that gives me output like this: `[{"propname","val1"},{"propname","val2"}]`. I am trying for something like `["val1","val2"]` which was possible with the `Query<string>` approach.

Answer (score 0):

Are you not re-throwing it?

```
throw;
```

Comment: I am rethrowing it to the API layer.